# add more to the first p tag and make the after content hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery

the HTML structure.

```
<div id="content">
<p>.....</p>
<p>.....</p>
<p>.....</p>
<p>.....</p>
</div>
```

now, i want to add a `more<<` text after the first paragraph, under default state. the others paragraph are hide, only display the  first paragraph content. when click the `more<<` then show the rest  paragraph content. is there a way to get this by jquery or javascript?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Was that all the information you needed, or do you want us to tell you how to do it?

Comment: come on guys, don't be harsh. It doesn't require allot of work.

Comment: Peter Of The Corn,if can,i want to you can give me some instrcutions,now, i want to select the first p. how to select it.i know $('p').first() can select the first p. but i want to add a condition to it. want to make the select in #content. how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('p:gt(0)').hide();
$('.more').click(function() {
    $('#content').find('p:gt(0)').slideToggle();
})
```

Click once to show all `<p>'s`, click again to hide them.

**Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/FUMuJ/**

Here's another example where `more` changes to `less` when clicked on and back

```
$('p:gt(0)').hide();
$('.more, .less').click(function() {
    $('#content').find('p:gt(0)').slideToggle();
    $('.more, .less').toggle();
})
```

**Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/FUMuJ/1/**

Comment: thank you,what's this p:gt(0) meaning? the more text is add by jquery.the default html structure is not added more text after the first parafraph.

Comment: `p:gt(0)` mean greater then the first p. 0 refers to first `p`

Comment: thank you,got it. but the default html structure is <p>aaaaa</p>, you can't add <span class="more"> | more</span><span class="less"> | less</span> default. is there a way to get that effect?

Comment: If you want to add it with jQuery. Check updated example at http://jsfiddle.net/FUMuJ/2/

Comment: i put this $('#content > p:gt(0)').append('<span class="more"> | more</span><span class="less"> | less</span>'); before you code,but it can't work.

Comment: I already gave you the updated link to check. You can find it at http://jsfiddle.net/FUMuJ/2. The first line is not the only thing i changed. I also changed `click()` to `live('click')`

Comment: thank you, what's the difference of the click() and live('click')

Comment: `live` is required for dynamically added elements that did not exist in your HTML initially. In this case it's the `more` and `less` that were added with jQuery. The only way to attached click events to them is to use `live`.

Comment: oh, jquery is too smart. i must  fall in love with it. ):

Comment: oh,damn it. i used drupal 6, the jquery's version is 1.26. it can't use the live() function, is there another function can instead?

Comment: No sure. This should be posted as a new question. It's unrelated to this post.